# Nuget not restoring symbols

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, nuget-server

We have a local nuget server on our build machine and publish our nuget packages to that server.  We create the packages with the -Symbols option to crteate a .symbols.nupkg package and that is what is copied to the packages directory on the server. (There was a problem putting both .nupkg files on the server as the restore failed to work.)

When we do a nuget restore we don't see any of the PDB files or sources in our dependent projects.  How do we get nuget to restore the symbols?

Comment: where are you trying to look for symbols , in the packages folder of your project , if yes then i don't think you will see your symbols there. you will see your symbols and src files in the symbols folders which you configured in visual studio.

see this link on how to configure symbol server.
http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio

Comment: Thanks @Prashant.  This seems to indicate that we need a separate server for symbol information.  We are using an internal nuget server.  Do we need to set up yet another nuget server for serving symbols?

Comment: so when you say symbol server are you using some third party tool or just a shared drive ?  because there can be different ways to get sysmbols based on what you use. if its third party like proget etc(which we use) yes they have a different url from the same deployment and everything works but if its a shared path we have to explore.

Comment: @prashant, I haven't set anything up yet as I thought both could go on the same server.  I had tried putting them in the same NuGet directory but hat didn't work.  Can I use the same NuGet server but put them in a different directory?